# PHP/Apache force download not working above 10MB

Tags: php, apache

I had to upgrade my server OS and re-install PHP and my PHP extensions which include APC.

But now when I use PHP to force a download it won't work when a file is above 10MB.

I'm using the same settings in PHP.ini so don't know what else could have changed.

Comment: What Apache version did to uprgade to/from?

Comment: I upgraded the OS not apache

Comment: Alright, my bad, but is it a secret?

Comment: No not at all -  2.2.3

Comment: You tell us that after the OS upgrade, you have a new problem. So it means that the OS is relevant. So then which OS is it? What version did you upgrade from and what version are you running now?

Comment: Actually I don't think it is related to the OS more that I had to re-install PHP and its extensions.

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes!

Comment: I downvoted your question because I don't want others to waste their time. As your answer suggests there was no way to understand your problem from the way your question was asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the downvotes this was solved with PHP by adding

```
ob_end_clean();
```

Before the header information, feel free to repeal your misinformed opinions.